# StringBuilder Error as "System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]

Tags: c#

When I am using `Split(',');` method I am getting output as "System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]

```
public string GetHrEmail()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var queryHrExeEmail = from cust in db.EMS_USER_MASTER
                          where cust.ROLE_ID == 17
                          select cust;

    foreach (EMS_USER_MASTER _userMaster in queryHrExeEmail)
    {
        sb.Append(_userMaster.EMAIL.Split(','));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `Split()` returns an array of strings, what do you want to do?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman  I wana to Print Names Like Abc,Apple,Mangoo..

Comment: Help us help you - please share an example `_userMaster.EMAIL` string and the output you'd want to get for it.

Comment: Can you post the content of `_userMaster.EMAIL`

Comment: @Mureinik  Im Getting OutPut as AppleMangoBanana  Like That But i need Separate By ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use string.join [check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
public string GetHrEmail() 
{
//get users with roleid= 17
var queryHrExeEmail = 
(from cust in db.EMS_USER_MASTER
where cust.ROLE_ID == 17
select cust);

 //selecting emails
var emailList=queryHrExeEmail.Select(e=>e.EMAIL);

//join selected emails with ,
return string.Join(",", emailList);

}
```

Comment: Thank u soo much for ur Value added Service